# How to set Phase algorithms in L2TP IPsec?

Tags: network, vpn

Good day, I am using Ubuntu often and it has l2tp newtwork manager, which allows me to connect via certain VPN. However, I use Mac more often and I want to set up the same mechanism and use VPN here.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I was setting VPN via `Settings -> Network`, there was no such option (Phase Algorithm) neither in `Authentication settings` nor in `Advanced`. Is there any way to set VPN without any other software, just using mac's VPN? Right now it doesn't work and I suppose that's due to the absence of the algorithms.

Mac OS: Monterey 12.3.1

Comment: You may want to try [IPSecuritas](https://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/) - I think it’s configurable there. (Oh sorry, just saw you don’t want to use other software for some reason.)

Comment: @not2savvy I just want to try with Apples' built-in tools, so I can get max out of all utilities. However, IPSecuritas may be a nice solution. So, in any cased many thx for the suggestion

Comment: @not2savvy Just tried it, there are no fields for login/pass auth. Either I confuse smth or it's just a bit different from what I need.

Comment: There should be. If you edit the connection, there's a tab "ID" for the authentication.  Note that you can select multiple types for identification and authentication method, and depending on the selected type, different entry fields appear.